# All outlook add-in could not be started in outlook2016, but all work for O365

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

My outlook add-in works in outlook365 but not outlook2016 client. I found a solution from the Internet:

> In Internet Explorer, click the Tools button, and then click Internet
>   Options. Click the Security tab, and then select the Internet Sites
>   Zone. Select the **Enable Protected Mode check box**, and then click
>   OK.

I did that, but no help.  I also installed Starbucks add-in and Yelp add-in. Then same thing happened,  all of them work for outlook365 but none of them work for our corporate outlook2016 client.

> Error Msg: This app could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore
>   the problem or click "Restart" to try again.

I suspect it might be some security issue, but I don't know where to check or debug.   Anyone here can give me some direction for where to check or thoughts?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: The **Enable Protected Mode** check box in **Internet Sites Zone** works. However, this checkbox might be disabled by your company's group policy. (That was where the issue.)